# How I am going to solve this [|x|] + [|2x|] = 7

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have tried to solve this greatest integer function problem like:
For all a ≤ x < a+1 then [|x|] = a
and then if 2a ≤ 2x < 2a+2 so

2a+1 ≤ 2x < 2a+2 then [|2x|]=2a+1
if i use this in equality
a + 2a+1 =7 so a=2 hence
5 ≤ 2x < 6 and 5/2 ≤ x <3 hence
ST = [5/2,3).
Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, except there are also negative solutions.

Comment: (There is also a small matter of an unjustified jump from $2a\le 2x\lt 2a+2$ to $2a+1\le 2x\lt 2a+2$. Of course it can be justified as follows: if, at the contrary, $2a\le 2x\lt 2a+1$, then $3a=7$, which has no solutions.)

Comment: In my experience, problems in this format may be routinely *vanquished* by specifying $x = A + r ~: ~A \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r < 1.$  This problem has the extra wrinkle of interrogating $|x|$ instead of merely interrogating $x$.  This is easily dealt with by breaking the problem into $2$ cases : $x \geq 0$, and $x < 0.$  Note that $x \geq 0 \iff (2x) \geq 0.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lfloor |x| \rfloor + \lfloor |2x| \rfloor =7$$
$$|x|=t, |2x|=2t \Rightarrow$$
$$\lfloor t \rfloor + \lfloor 2t \rfloor = 7$$
$$\lfloor t \rfloor = u \Rightarrow u \leq t < u+1 \Rightarrow$$
$$2u \leq 2t < 2u+2 \Rightarrow \lfloor 2t \rfloor = 2u \lor \lfloor 2t \rfloor = 2u+1 \Rightarrow$$
$$u+2u=7 \lor u+2u+1 =7 \Rightarrow 3u=7 \lor 3u+1=7\Rightarrow u=7/3 \lor u=2$$
$$u\in\mathbb{Z} \Rightarrow u=2 \Rightarrow \lfloor 2t \rfloor = 7-\lfloor t \rfloor = 7-u = 5 \Rightarrow$$
$$2 \leq t < 3 \land 5 \leq 2t < 6 \Rightarrow 5/2 \leq t < 3 \Rightarrow$$
$$5/2 \leq |x| < 3 \Rightarrow x \in (-3;-2.5]\cup[2.5;3)$$

Comment: thank you for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Let $z:=|x|=n+f$ (integer and fractional parts).

$$[z]+[2z]=3n+[2f]=7.$$

As the fractional part is in $[0,1)$, the only option is

$$n=2,[2f]=1$$ so that $f\in[\frac12,1)$ and $|x|\in[\frac52,3)$.